# Showing listfragment in action bar

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am working on my first android app so forgive me if this is a simple question. The app currently has five tabs (made using fragments) and I am currently trying to set up a ListFragment in the first tab.

In my MainActivity class I have the code:

```
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    if (tab.getPosition() == 0) {
        TopRatedListFragment topRatedListFragment = new TopRatedListFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, topRatedListFragment).commit();
    } else {
        Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, tab.getPosition() + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
    }
```

Now this works fine for my "DummySectionFragment"s. But my TopRatedListFragment extends ListFragment instead of just Fragment... so therefore the above code is giving me issues.

The line:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, topRatedListFragment).commit();
```

is the one drawing the error and saying the .replace method doesn't like the topRatedListedFragment argument since it is a ListFragment and not a regular Fragment.

How should I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, your imports and/or class definitions are messed up.

There are two implementations of `Fragment`, `ListFragment`, and `FragmentTransaction`. One set is in `android.app`. The other set is in `android.support.v4.app`. These are not compatible. You use the latter pair if you are using `FragmentActivity` for the Android Support package's backport of fragments.

My guess is that your `FragmentTransaction` and your `ListFragment` are coming from different packages, one from `android.app` and one from `android.support.v4.app`. If so, you need to fix that, having both use the same package, whichever one is appropriate for your circumstances.

Comment: Ahh that would do it. Can you explain the difference between android.app and android.support.v4.app? What is the difference and which is usually better?

Comment: @user1434066: "Can you explain the difference between android.app and android.support.v4.app?" -- as I wrote, the latter is the Android Support package's backport of fragments. "What is the difference" -- the backport works back to Android 1.6 (API Level 4) but requires a JAR. The native fragments requires no JAR but only work on API Level 11 and higher devices. "which is usually better?" -- use the backport if you are looking to ship to API Level 10 or lower devices. Otherwise, do not use the backport.